# How do you create resource route when the item has optional child items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do you create routes for models that have option child properties?  Say I am creating a help desk app, and the ticket could be associated with an order that the customer had previously had with me, or it could be regarding an item in the catalog they have not yet ordered.

```
class CustomerServiceTicket
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :buyer
  belongs_to :customer_service_category
end

class Order
  ...
  has_one :customer_service_ticket
  ...
end

class Item
  ...
  has_one :customer_service_ticket
  ...
end
```

in the schema for customer_service_ticket, order_id and item_id are nullable.

So I'll have a 'create a customer service ticket' link next to their say their order_id's on the their closed orders page...and a similar link next to the item_id on the product catalog page.

I'm thinking the url structure should look like this:

customer_service_ticket/new/order/123

for tickets created relating to an order

and

customer_service_ticket/new/item/789

for tickets created relating to an item

and just
customer_service_ticket/new
when there is neither (also valid for cases where the customer just has a general question)

How would I structure the routes to be the most efficient?  I'm not married to that URL structure above, if there is a better way I'm happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you describe your routes, it sounds like the orders and items already exist at the time you need to create a new customer service ticket, is that correct?  If so, then it would be better to create your routes like this:

```
orders/123/customer_service_ticket/new
items/123/customer_service_ticket/new
customer_service_tickets/new
```

Any time you are adding a resource onto an existing resource, the new resource typically goes at the end, with the action you are performing being the last portion of the URL.  To create this structure it would be something like this:

```
resources :orders do
  resource :customer_service_ticket
end

resources :items do
  resource :customer_service_ticket
end

resources :customer_service_ticket
```

However, you may also want to rethink your relationships.  Once a customer service is closed for an order/item, are you certain there will never be another customer service ticket relating to that order/item?  That may indicate a `has_many` relationship.  You may also want to look into a polymorphic relationship for orders and items to customer service tickets.  That way if you want to add more entities that can relate to customer service tickets, you don't have to keep adding database fields.  Note that changing to a `has_many` would change the routes declarations above slightly.